# Playwright, method "is_visible()" always returns False for the page title

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I print out the title, then put it into the function "is_visible()"
It always returns False, but it should be True since I use the title the computer returns to me.
Any solution?

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from playwright.sync_api import expect, Page


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=1000)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto('https://www.duckduckgo.com')
    page.locator('#search_form_input_homepage').fill('panda')
    page.locator('#search_button_homepage').click()
    expect(page).to_have_title('panda at DuckDuckGo')
    print(page.title())
    print(page.get_by_title('panda at DuckDuckGo').is_visible())
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be confusing two things:

1. The page title, which is the thing you see written in the browser tab. For this page, running `document.title` in the browser console gives `'python - Playwright, method "is_visible()" always returns False - Stack Overflow'`. You can assert that the page title has a certain value with [`to_have_title()`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-pageassertions#page-assertions-to-have-title), as you're correctly doing.
2. An element's `title` attribute. This is not the page title, rather, it's `<span title="Issues count">25 issues</span>`. You can retrieve this element with [`get_by_title()`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-locator#locator-get-by-title).

With this in mind,

```py
print(page.get_by_title('panda at DuckDuckGo').is_visible())
```

doesn't make sense. It's confusing the page title with the `title=` attribute of an element. No element in the DOM has a `title="panda at DuckDuckGo"` so the locator times out.

I suppose you could retrieve the `<title>panda at DuckDuckGo</title>` element with a `page.locator("title")` and assert its contents, but I don't see the point to doing that since `to_have_title` already achieves this more succinctly.

In short, remove the `get_by_title` line. There's no need to check the visibility of a page title--you've already asserted all there is to assert about the page title with `to_have_title()`.